# CancellationToken blocks thread execution

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

I'm trying to use cancellation tokens to break out of a loop from another thread:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CancellationTokenTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static CancellationTokenSource token;

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            token = new CancellationTokenSource();
            var t1 = LongProcess1();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    await Task.Delay(2000, token.Token);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Main awaited {i}");
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Main loop completed");
            t1.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Application end");
        }

        static async Task LongProcess1()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Console.WriteLine($"LongProcess1 awaited {i}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Submitting cancel");
            token.Cancel();     // <------ Blocking execution
            Console.WriteLine("Cancellation done!");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the line `Console.WriteLine("Cancellation done!");` never gets executed, and the `Main()` method keeps waiting for `t1` to complete.

I do not understand why!

I ran this on .NET 5, but it doesn't seem to be framework dependent.
Can someone help me understand what's going on?

Comment: Remove `t1.Wait();`. It's causing a deadlock. When `Cancel()` is called, the thread *enters* back into your `for` loop in your `Main` - but then that thread is blocked by `t1.Wait()` which stops it from then continuing inside `LongProcess1`.

Comment: I note that your program **is not multi-threaded** - that's why it's encountering a deadlock. The best solution is not to start using threads, but to keep on using a single-thread and eliminate old-fashioned blocking operations.

Comment: If I remove the `t1.Wait()` the "Cancellation done!" happens after the "Application end" (and I did not think it was possible...). Adding a Delay after the Cacel causes the "Cancellation done!" to never happen. Is there a way to make it happen before the "Application end" ?

Comment: @Dai .... have you ever developed a single multithreaded app?

Comment: @MartinJames I admit I used an _excessively simple_ explanation when I wrote that the "program is not multi-threaded" which is not technically correct (indeed, at Stephen's answer says, it uses the Thread-Pool). What I meant was that the OP's program _will only ever have a single thread running user-code at any point-in-time_ - not that a single thread will ever exist in their process' user-code - or did you have a different point to make?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This deadlock is almost exactly like the one [described on my blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html). One thing you need to be aware of is that `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel` in this case is running the cancellation token continuations *on the thread that calls `Cancel`*.

So, here's what's happening:

- `Main` starts `LongProcess`.
- `LongProcess` uses some `await`s and resumes on a thread pool thread.
- In the meantime, `Main` is doing an `await Task.Delay`.
- When `LongProcess` does the `Cancel`, it actually resumes executing the `Main` method *on the current thread*. You can verify this by placing a breakpoint in your `catch` block and looking at the call stack.
- The current thread (a thread pool thread) then blocks on the task (`.Wait()`).
- Now, `LongProcess` cannot complete because the thread currently running it is blocked waiting for it to complete.

To fix it, change the `Wait()` to an `await`.

Comment: Thank you, this solved. I will be pleased to read about this on your blog!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `t1.Wait();` (`Wait()` is *almost always* the problem ;p) - this is stealing the thread. Use `await t1;` instead, and everything will work. Effectively, the *cancellation* needs to invoke some callbacks (the continuations in the cancellation state) and then return to whatever did the cancellation, and you've inserted a blockage into the cancellation.